Solve for $x$: $\ a^3x^3+b^3=0\ \ \ $ The constants $a,b$ represent positive real numbers.

Solve for $x$:  $\  a^3x^3+b^3=0\ \ \ $ The constants $a,b$ represent positive real numbers.

$a^3x^3=-b^3$
$x^3=\dfrac{-b^3}{a^3}$
$\sqrt[3]{x^3}=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{-b^3}{a^3}}$
$x=\dfrac{bi}{a}$
But when you plug it back in, it does not work. Why?

Where does $i$ come from?

There is a real cube root of $-1,$ namely $-1.$   Next, there are complex cube roots of $+1,$   namely $ \frac{-1 \pm i \sqrt 3}{2}$  Once you have the real solution $x = \frac{-b}{a},$   multiplying by cube roots of one gives the two complex values for $x$

I confused $\sqrt{-1}=i$ with $\sqrt[3]{-1}=i$. Thanks for the help guys.

You seem to be mistaking here:
$$i^2=-1 \text{ (second power)}$$
$$(-1)^3 = -1 \text{ (third power)}$$

$$b^3+a^3x^3=0\implies a^3x^3=-b^3\implies x^3=-\frac{b^3}{a^3}\\ $$
Taking the cube root of both sides gives $\sqrt[3]{-\frac{b^3}{a^3}}$ times the third roots of unity
$$x=-\frac{b}{a}\lor x=\frac{\sqrt[3]{-1}b}{a}\lor x=-\frac{(-1)^{2/3}b}{a}$$
